# read specific line from txt file java

Tags: java, string, inputstream, outputstream

i have a question! I have a txt file (in a specific path that don't move) that contains a string which content is variable. i must use this string for input of my algorithm.
A example of solution of txt file is

```
50 [40,-13,-6,-7,-4] [28,-40,45,-29,37] [-43,19,-24,-9,-45] [26,-41,-28,-16,44]
```

or

```
4 [-3,-1,2] [-2,-4,1] [-3,2,1] [-2,3,-4] [4,2,1] [4,-1,2] [3,-4,1] [-3,-2,-4]
```

I must use the number 50 or 4 or another number out of brackets as a int. but  all the rest of the content must be extracted in a particular string that after will pass to a method. 
anyone have a solution? 
IMPORTANT: the contents of the file is variable

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: if possible, a kind of implementation of a method that can acquire the result and about something about how to convert.

Comment: Read about [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: You've told us some possible solutions - what are the inputs for those solutions?

Comment: Thank u, but about the start and the end of the string (that is variable), how can I define it?

Comment: @Bakstar I must use the number 50 or 4 or another number out of brackets as a int. but all the rest of the content must be extracted in a particular string that after will pass to a method ( String [])

Comment: Use String Tokenizer for every line you read.First token will give you the integer, remaining tokens can be merged into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/Application/testdata/ntd.txt` is the path of your txt file then below code will work (what i guess is your requirement).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        String content=null;
        File folder = new File("/Application/testdata/ntd.txt");

              content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder)+"\n";
              System.out.println(content);


        int outside=Integer.parseInt(content.substring(0, content.indexOf("[")).trim());
        System.out.println("int val: "outside);
        String remainingString=content.substring(content.indexOf("["), content.lastIndexOf("]")+1);
        System.out.println("String value: "remainingString);
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
  50 [40,-13,-6,-7,-4] [28,-40,45,-29,37] [-43,19,-24,-9,-45] [26,-41,-28,-16,44]
  int val: 50
  String value: [40,-13,-6,-7,-4] [28,-40,45,-29,37] [-43,19,-24,-9,-45] [26,-41,-28,-16,44]
```

I used apache commons for file read. If you waNT to break `remainingString` further then split it according to SPACE character.

Comment: Thank you for help, your solution is ok for my problem but for example If I wanted to have String remainingString as array of string, how should I do?